# Group the data points rows into coloumns

Tags: excel

I have a data file in which the rows have the same value and have corresponding value divided in rows . I want to group the rows and transpose the rows having different values in columns.

```
+----------+-------+-----------+-----------------------+
|    id    | price | featureId |      featureName      |
+----------+-------+-----------+-----------------------+
| 82979304 | 32749 |      7174 | Yes                   |
| 82979304 | 32749 |       110 | Intel Core i3         |
| 82979304 | 32749 |      6093 | Intel                 |
| 82979304 | 32749 |       194 | 4 GB                  |
| 82979304 | 32749 |       201 | 15.6 inches(39.62 cm) |
| 82979304 | 32749 |      5398 | Laptop                |
| 82979304 | 32749 |      8904 | Lenovo G50-80         |
| 82979304 | 32749 |       143 | 501 GB -1 TB          |
| 82979304 | 32749 |       145 | DOS                   |
| 84425999 | 37999 |       110 | Intel Core i5         |
| 84425999 | 37999 |      6093 | Intel                 |
| 84425999 | 37999 |       194 | More than 8 GB        |
| 84425999 | 37999 |      5398 | Laptop                |
| 84425999 | 37999 |       143 | Upto 500 GB           |
| 84425999 | 37999 |      2762 | Integrated            |
| 84425999 | 37999 |      6097 | Intel                 |
| 84425999 | 37999 |      5868 | Seller Warranty       |
+----------+-------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

So ID 82979304 Will be grouped as one and the corresponding rows of same id will become columns.

Update : I am using this formula for doing the part 
=TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("$C"&D2&":$C"&(D2+9)))

which is an array formula . I have got the answer for one row . But when I am applying to other rows by selecting the cell range and using Ctrl+Shift+Enter , I am unable to get the result . It is getting the same result across the entire range . I want the D2 value to increase one by one i.e D2 then D3 and so on.

Any solution ?

Comment: This will get very ugly, very fast.  Why do you need this output?

Comment: I am trying to run K Means algo on the data , thought of creating dummies but ended up with 213 columns . Any other way out ? Like creating ordinal transformation ?

Comment: So you want to make a pivot table?

Comment: Not a pivot , just separate the rows into columns , so that I can run the K means on data.

Comment: Still sounds like pivoting to me. Please add the expected result to your questions.

Comment: Will transposing them helps ?

Comment: Kindly show us the output how your expecting to be transposed it